# create a matrix with four column and 5 rows using the sample provided in python

Tags: python, list, matrix

I have 5 lists below:

```
[(0, 0.014), (1, 0.95), (2, 0.01), (3, 0.01)]
[(0, 0.01), (1, 0.01), (2, 0.012), (3, 0.94)]
[(0, 0.945), (1, 0.018), (2, 0.0184), (3, 0.0183)]
[(0, 0.012), (1, 0.023), (2, 0.011), (3, 0.965)]
[(0, 0.022), (1, 0.023), (2, 0.931), (3, 0.024)]
```

how can I have a 1D matrix I mean a matrix out of this in a way I have four column and 5 rows
so the output should be :

```
[[(0, 0.014), (1, 0.95), (2, 0.01), (3, 0.01)],
 [(0, 0.01), (1, 0.01), (2, 0.012), (3, 0.94)],
 [(0, 0.945), (1, 0.018), (2, 0.0184), (3, 0.0183)],
 [(0, 0.012, (1, 0.023), (2, 0.011), (3, 0.965)],
 [(0, 0.022), (1, 0.023), (2, 0.931), (3, 0.024)]]
```

I dont want an array with one row and all examples as column, I want exactly four columns and 5 rows as instances.
for more explanations: its a matrix that rows save document ID and columns are features.
Thanks

**Update**
this is 5 lists, I am going to merge them in one matrix with 4 columns and 5 rows

Comment: You said you don't want an array with one row but your current output looks like one. Also you are missing some `,` in your output example

Comment: So basically, you are looking for someone to write the solution so that you can cut and paste it in your code?

Comment: @OLIVER.KOO so you are correct, thanks for the comment

Comment: @ImanolLuengo not that much, I tried various ways, but as stuck in part of project tired to explain. its an input to multinomial SVM , ...but you are right also :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ummm put those 5 lists `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`  in a list call `matrix`

`matrix = [a,b,c,d,e]` then you get a matrix.

and to access the matrix. ex:  get the third row second column `print(matrix[2][1])` you get `(1, 0.018)`